# Memcached+PHP session, write() is not working?

Tags: php, session

I am trying to save my session into memcached, here is some code:

```
class MemcacheHandler implements \SessionHandlerInterface
{
    public function write($session_id, $session_data)
    {
        $mc = self::getMc();
        # test file
        file_put_contents('/tmp/session_test', $session_id.'-'.$session_data.'-'.self::$config['expire'].PHP_EOL, FILE_APPEND);
        return $mc->set($session_id, $session_data, self::$config['expire']);
    }

    # Omitting some code
    # read() close() destroy() open() gc() getMc() .....
}
```

Next

```
session_set_save_handler(new MemcacheHandler(), true);
session_start();
$_SESSION['uid'] = 123456;  # write some data
```

My question is, when i request to the server, There will be a record in `/tmp/session_test` like `6n0vam0oo8keadg1nl1qab8633-uid|s:6:"123456";-1200`。

But when I `refresh` the page, no record is written! so, if i set up a user login/logout system using session，Would not it be more than a `expire` time, the user is automatically dropped？

If I changed `$_SESSION['uid'] = 78965;` Record will be overwritten。Is not php will determine the session_data has changed before write? If there is no change, no write？

My english is poor。。thanks for your time :)